# Covid-19 incubation period for vaccinated people

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, immune-system

1The incubation period for covid-19 can be even something like 14 days. I guess this can be caused by having no specific immunity to this disease, so it takes some time for the immune system to react. And since some of the perceptible symptoms (e.g., fever) are caused by the immune system, the incubation period can be long.

However, if a vaccinated person is infected despite the vaccination (as it is not 100% protection), does the immunity lower the incubation period? How much? I believe it is reasonable to expect it, as the immune system has at least some idea how to react to the specific disease. This would mean getting the fever earlier, but in a milder way. However, I might have missed something or I might have just discovered some factor with minimum impact. I was unable to find if and how much important factor it is.

Comment: `"The incubation period for covid-19 can be even something like 14 days."` -- Where did you read that? This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research, and it sounds like you've done some, but you need to include a link to things like this in your question to demonstrate it, It doesn't have to be everything, but the more you support with references, the better your question.

Comment: @CareyGregory “The incubation period of COVID-19, which is the time between exposure to the virus and symptom onset, is on average 5-6 days, but can be as long as 14 days.” https://www.who.int/news-room/commentaries/detail/transmission-of-sars-cov-2-implications-for-infection-prevention-precautions

Comment: Re: "I guess this can be caused by having no specific immunity to this disease, so it takes some time for the immune system to react" I would think it would be the opposite, that an immune response suppresses the virus enough that there isn't enough of it to cause symptoms until more days have passed.  Remember too that the body has non-specific innate immunity as well as specific immunity.

Comment: @v6ak Thank you. Now can you please edit your question to include the link and quote?